# Dynamically Creating PDF in Struts 2

Tags: struts2

Good Evening ;

I have a problem that I am working on struts2 web application. I am dynamically creating a PDF using data base. i want to show it in a web page but I don`t know how I do it is any one can help me.

Thanks...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265702/pdf-generation-using-itext-in-struts-2-result-type-stream-not-working) is an answer using iText and `HttpServletResponse OutputStream`.

Answer (score 5):

Action code:

```
public class PDFAction extends ActionSupport {
    private InputStream inputStream;

public String getPDF(){       
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);

        document.open();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add("INSTITUTO POLITÉCNICO NACIONAL, ESCUELA SUPERIOR DE CÓMPUTO, DIEGO A. RAMOS");

        document.add(p);
        document.close();

        inputStream  =  new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray());

   return SUCCESS;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}
}
```

Struts.xml:

```
<action name="getPDF" class="action.PDFAction" method="getPDF">
       <result name="success" type="stream">
            <param name="inputName">inputStream</param> 
            <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param> 
            <param name="contentDisposition">filename="mypdf.pdf"</param> 
            <param name="bufferSize">2048</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

Try it, it works like a charm, works perfect for me. If you are in doubt read more about stream result type that Struts 2 provides. The answer to this is so simple yet it was hard to get to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the content using the input stream or best way is to create custom result type where you can set appropriate header and other things here is a link for some help

[Struts2 Custom Result Type](http://markjgreene.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/struts-2-with-scriptaculous-autocompleter/)

Answer (score 1):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);
document.open();
////Do your stuff here
document.close();
DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
{
dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);
}
```

I m using iText for creating pdf. You can put this scriptlet in a jsp and call this jsp to show the pdf generated