# PDF generation using iText in Struts-2 : result type stream not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, struts2, itext

My requirement is to generate PDF file using iText, I use below code to create a sample PDF

```
Document document = new Document();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("success PDF FROM STRUTS"));
document.close();
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream() ;
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"stuReport.pdf\"");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

If you see in the above code, iText is not using any inputStream parameter, rather it is writing directly to response's outputstream. Whereas struts-2 is mandating us to use InputStream parameter (see the configuration below)

```
<action name="exportReport" class="com.export.ExportReportAction">
    <result name="pdf" type="stream">
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="sample.pdf"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

I know that my class should have getters and setters for inputStream and i have that too in the class mentioned in struts-configuration

```
private InputStream inputStream;
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}

public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    this.inputStream = inputStream;
}
```

But since iText doesn't really need inputstream rather it is writing directly to response's outputstream, i get exceptions since am not setting anything for the inputStream parameter.

Please let me know how to use iText code in struts-2 having the resultType as stream

Thanks

Comment: are you getting illegal state exception ??

Comment: Yes chaitanya.. you are right . I get illegal state exception, asking me to check <param name="inputName">

Comment: i have deleted my answer. seems like i was wrong. as said i am not familiar with struts

Comment: You can create the inputstream from the output stream:  `setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));`

Comment: Click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137362/struts2-display-pdf-file-in-jsp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648987/dynamically-creating-pdf-in-struts-2) for solutions using Dave Newton's suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution to this.

The method in the action which performs this PDF export can be void. The result type configuration is not needed while we are writing directly to response's outputstream

for example, have your action class this way

```
Class ExportReportAction extends ActionSupport {
  public void exportToPdf() { // no return type
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("success PDF FROM STRUTS"));
        document.close(); 
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream() ; 
        baos.writeTo(outputStream); 
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"stuReport.pdf\""); 
        response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
        outputStream.flush(); 
        outputStream.close(); 
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //catch
    }

  } 
}
```

and have your struts-configuration this way

```
<action name="exportReport" class="com.export.ExportReportAction"> 
 <!-- NO NEED TO HAVE RESULT TYPE STREAM CONFIGURATION-->
</action>
```

this works cool !!!

Thanks for all who attempted to answer this question

Comment: IMO this isn't a great solution, although it works. S2 provides a mechanism for this, the stream result, that should be preferred to doing everything manually in Java code.

Comment: @DaveNewton : S2's resultType stream always looks for java.io.InputStream object to be filled in code. Inputstream can be filled when you are reading a PDF file from a file system or any other input-system. Whereas iText creates a PDF writes it directly to response's outputstream. That being the case, we dont need any inputstream and also iText need any inputstream to write. So this solutions sounds good to me :-)

Comment: It's a one-liner to get an input stream from an output stream. Configuration is more flexible via XML, and normalized against the rest of the system. I'm not arguing to *never* write directly to the response, but when you don't *need* to, it seems a waste. Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

### Main Answer:

You can also **`return NONE`** or **`return null`** as explained in the Apache docs:

> Returning **ActionSupport.NONE (or null)** from an action class method
>   causes the results processing to be skipped. This is useful if the
>   action fully handles the result processing such as writing directly to
>   the HttpServletResponse OutputStream.
>
> ***Source:*** http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/result-configuration.html

---

### Example:

O'Reilly offers a tutorial on [Dynamically Creating PDFs in a Web Application](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/06/18/dynamic_files.html?page=1) using Servlets (S.C. Sullivan, 2003). It can be converted to a Struts2 action class as shown below.

It is good to have a helper class like `PDFGenerator` to create the PDF for you and return it as a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

**`PDFGenerator` class**:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*;

public class PDFGenerator {

    public ByteArrayOutputStream generatePDF() throws DocumentException {

        Document doc = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baosPDF);

        try {           
            doc.open();         

            // create pdf here
            doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));

        } catch(DocumentException de) {
            baosPDF.reset();
            throw de;

        } finally {
            if(doc != null) {
                doc.close();
            }

            if(pdfWriter != null) {
                pdfWriter.close();
            }
        }

        return baosPDF;
    }
}
```

You can now call it in your action class.

**`ViewPDFAction` class**:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletResponseAware;
import com.yoursite.helper.PDFGenerator;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class ViewPDFAction extends ActionSupport
    implements ServletResponseAware {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baosPDF = new PDFGenerator().generatePDF();    
        String filename = "Your_Filename.pdf"; 

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "inline; filename=" + filename); // open in new tab or window           
        response.setContentLength(baosPDF.size());

        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        os.write(baosPDF.toByteArray());
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        baosPDF.reset();

        return NONE; // or return null
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;       
    }
}
```

**`web.xml`**:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>pdf</extension>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="viewpdf" class="com.yoursite.action.ViewPDFAction">
    <!-- NO CONFIGURATION FOR RESULT NONE -->
</action>
```

Comment: Updated answer for PDF generation.